# Copying Xcode installation from one Mac to another

Tags: macos, xcode

I have installed 3 different versions of Xcode on my Mac.

Can I just copy the `/Applications/Xcode*.app` app bundles from my Mac and put it on other 10 Macs I have? I don't want to go through the hassle of downloading and installing it again.

Has anyone done this successfully?

**NOTE**: I saw another question on copying to an external drive. I am NOT doing that. Just copying from one machine to another and keeping the installations in `/Applications` folder.

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks. Have you successfully done that before?

Comment: I think I was wrong. I do copy stuff on the same machine. It will probably not work on another machine. At least not without downloading all simulators and other stuff. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I Wanted to close the loop on this. Yes, it works just fine. We create a .xip file of the installation and slap it on other boxes.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the Xcode application from /Applications folder of one machine  to another machine. No problem , it will work. But i recommend you to copy the xcode to desktop(or some other folder otherthan /Applications ) of the second machine initially and then move to /Applications folder.

Comment: Please explain the rational of "_But i recommend you to copy the xcode to desktop(or some other folder otherthan /Applications ) of the second machine initially and then move to /Applications folder_"

Comment: @Aadu Thoma: yes, could you let me know why that is needed?

Comment: Technically i don't know , but i had tried that before and worked for me.